# Expect Script - String com caracteres especiais

Tags: script

Estou montando um script de conexão usando `expect`, `spawn`, `send`, etc

Meu problema está na hora de inserir a senha.

A senha que estou testando é **teste!Q@W#E$R**, o problema que quando executo ele retorna:

> ```
> can't read "R": no such variable
>     while executing
> "send "teste!Q@W#E$R""
> ```

Ou seja, ele está dando escape bem no final, no **$R**.

Alguém sabe como eu faço ele ignorar a função do **$** e considerar o mesmo como parte da string?

---

Segue o script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /opt/forticlient-sslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server <IP>:<PORTA> --vpnuser <USER>
expect "Password for VPN:"
send $'teste!Q@W#E$R'
expect "*(Y/N)"
send "Y\r"
interact
```

Comment: Acho que o sistema está interpretando o `$`, tenta usar assim `send 'teste!Q@W#E$R'`, com `''` ao invés de `""`

Comment: Oi Denis, agradeço a atenção. Mas eu testei aqui e não deu certo também

Comment: Seria isso que você está procurando? `send $'teste!Q@W#E$R'`

Comment: Oi Ronaldo, boa tarde, obrigado por responder.. mas ainda não deu certo

can't read "R": no such variable
    while executing
"send $'teste!Q@W#E$R'"

Comment: É shell script que você está usando, certo?

Comment: mandei o script no comentário abaixo

Comment: Tentou `send 'teste!Q@W#E$R'` ? Sem o `$`

Comment: O script funciona, testei com outro user e senha e foi de boa

Comment: sim, testei também sem o $  e da na mesma

Comment: eu vi também que o mesmo erro ocorre para senhas com *(asterisco)